# Record Quickblox Video Chat

Tags: android, video, screenshot, quickblox, video-recording

I am using QuickBlox,I want to record video chat and can access later.Documentation says that Video Chat can be recorded.
I can handle all datas using this

```
private OnQBVideoChatListener qbVideoChatListener = new OnQBVideoChatListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCameraDataReceive(byte[] videoData) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMicrophoneDataReceive(byte[] audioData) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpponentVideoDataReceive(byte[] videoData) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpponentAudioDataReceive(byte[] audioData) {
    }

};
```

I want to know how can I record this videoData or other solution. please help

Answer (score 0):

The byte array is actually one single frame of the video stream.

You can get the image as follows:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(videoData, 0, videoData.length);
```

To get a video i think you would need to render it yourself.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also can look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html

To write own video you should merge audio and video streams from these callbacks:

```
@Override
public void onCameraDataReceive(byte[] videoData) {

}

@Override
public void onMicrophoneDataReceive(byte[] audioData) {
}
```

To write opponent's video you should merge audio and video streams from these callbacks:

```
@Override
public void onOpponentVideoDataReceive(byte[] videoData) {
}

@Override
public void onOpponentAudioDataReceive(byte[] audioData) {
}
```